# Random video (from pool of around 10) show up on a web page

Tags: video, random

I am needing to create a page that would have an embedded video on the page. The client would like for if you were to refresh your page though, it would be a different video ( more than likely ). Apparently they will have like 10-15 different videos.

Does anybody have any experience with this with a "tablet friendly" method? No flash.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

here is a very simple implementation for the requirement u have provided

```
  have an array of 15+ videos
  videos = [] 
  videos[0] = "url of the video"
  videos[1] = "url of 2nd video"
   .. and so on


   var vid = Math.floor(Math.random()*15);

  document.getElementsByTagname("object")[0].src = videos[vid];
```

will load a new video on refreshing the page